# How to remove last asterisk from output generated by loop?

Tags: java, syntax, syntax-error

```
import java.util.*;
public class factorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a number");
      int n=sc.nextInt();
        long fact=1;
        System.out.println("Calculations: ");
        for(long i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            fact=fact*i;
            System.out.print(i+" ");
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\nThe factorial is: "+fact);
    }

}
```

this is my code for the factorial program, when i print this..i get something like this 
Enter a number
4
Calculations: 
1 *2 *3 *4 *
The factorial is: 24

can anyone tell me how to remove that additional "*" from output

Comment: So you want your loop to print * only `if(it is NOT last iteration)`. How we can check if it is last iteration? Do we have any variables which we can use to determine it?

Comment: since multiplication by `1` is not needed, print the `1` and start the loop with `2` printing the `*` before the number is printed

Answer (score 1):

```
for(long i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    fact=fact*i;
    System.out.print(i+" ");
    if(i!=n)
        System.out.print("*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One has no access to the System.out line buffer, hence the solution must take itself that there is no additional asterisk:

```
    for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i != 1) {
            System.out.print(" * ");
        }
        fact *= i;
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: @user85421 you are right, after typing it already irritated me. I meant what I wrote now. Thanks, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

updated code -  you need to check `if(i!=n)`

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        long fact=1;
        System.out.println("Calculations: ");
        for(long i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
        fact=fact*i;
        System.out.print(i+" ");
        if(i!=n)
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\nThe factorial is: "+fact);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class factorial {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    long fact=1;
    System.out.println("Calculations: ");
    for(long i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
      fact=fact*i;
      System.out.print(i+" ");
      if(i<n) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
    }
    System.out.print("\nThe factorial is: "+fact);
  }

}
```